# Using jQuery to sort li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that I use to sort a list of `li`'s, however it is not working when there is more than one digit, it is sorting with the first digit taking preference, so 10 comes before 2. Is there a way to modify this so it sorts it based on the numeric value?

```
jQuery.fn.sortDomElements = (function() {
    return function(comparator) {
        return Array.prototype.sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i) {
              this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
        });
    };
})();

$("#sortable3, #sortable4").children().sortDomElements(function(a,b){
    akey = $(a).attr("sortkey");
    bkey = $(b).attr("sortkey");
    if (akey == bkey) return 0;
    if (akey < bkey) return -1;
    if (akey > bkey) return 1;
});
```

Comment: You need to convert the 'sortkey' attributes to integer, as they are being compared as strings right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing strings. When comparing strings you get this:

```
"10" <  "2"
true
```

Instead force the string to ints base 10:

```
parseInt("10", 10) <  parseInt("1", 10)
false
```

Trying this:

```
$("#sortable3, #sortable4").children().sortDomElements(function(a,b){
    akey = parseInt(($(a).attr("sortkey"), 10);
    bkey = parseInt($(b).attr("sortkey"), 10);
    if (akey == bkey) return 0;
    if (akey < bkey) return -1;
    if (akey > bkey) return 1;
});
```

should fix it.

Comment: I would suggest always specifying the expected radix for `parseInt()`

Comment: Yes, you're right @jdphenix, that's an accepted best practice — edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the key to a number.

```
akey = parseInt($(a).attr("sortkey");
...
```

Comment: I would suggest always specifying the expected radix for `parseInt()`